# Logic error with moving all files in a folder

Tags: python-3.x

I am writing two simple scripts, one to move all files into a folder, and one to move all files back to said folder. I am not getting any errors, but the files aren't moving so I am likely missing something stupidly obvious somewhere.

I tried making sure the file paths were correct, looked up how the syntax of the commands worked, and checked for any basic errors.

```
import shutil
import os

source = r'C:\\Users\JonTh\Saved Games\DCS\Mods\aircraft'
destination = r'C:\\Users\JonTh\Saved Games\dcs planes'

files = os.listdir(source)

for index in files:
    shutil.move(source,destination)
```

Comment: Why did you specify the double backslash here: `C:\\Users` ?

Comment: Your `for` loop is not using the files at all, and is just repeatedly calling `shutil.move` on the source folder. That should still do something though. Are you sure the `destination` directory remains empty?

Comment: Yes I didn't see anything move, I checked both folders.

Answer (score 1):

you should modify your code to consider files from for loop

```
for index in files:
    shutil.move(source+"\\"+index,destination)
```

Comment: from his source and destination locations it doesn't seem like he's using linux/MacOS, so  `/` will not work for him, I would suggest you to change it with a backslash and do something like `shutil.move(source+"\\"+index,destination)`

Comment: @VasuDeo.S good catch as i have linux so i just pasted that, will modify the answer.

Comment: It's even better to use os.path.join() - os.path.join(source,index) - this way, it's system indepenten

Comment: pardon my ignorance, but what does the index part of that line do? I thought the move function just called a address for source and a address for destination